# Akka remote configuration best practice

Tags: configuration, akka, akka-remote-actor

I want to set up several actor systems on the same host. In the future some of the actor systems could be moved to another host. The actors in the actor system communicate with each other.

My idea would be that all actor systems (on the same host) share a one configuration file which could be defined as the system property config.resource, so I do not get into a muddle with different configuration files.

But I am unsure how the configuration file should look best. I could define the actor path (like "akka.tcp://actorSystemName@10.0.0.1:2552/user/actorName") but this does not help me for actor creation. It is only useful for accessing as remote actor. I could define another variable actorName for creation. But then I have two variables for one actorName.

Best way is I think to define actorSystemName, host and port for each system and actorNames for each actor and then create the path from all these variables. But with this approach I think it is not possible to access childactors.

How do you configure your actor systems? Do you use one or several configs?

Comment: Look here: http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/simple-akka-remote-example/ might help you.

Comment: This is just a general configuration. To access the remote actor in step 3 the path is still hard coded (which is really bad for a production system IMHO). I would prefer one config for all systems and no hard coded strings.